# Calling a non-static member function without creating an instance

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am a newbie in object oriented approach and C++ programming as well:
My question is: How can a class pointer which is not instantiating any object can call the member function of that class. below is the working code which I tried today

```
#include <iostream>


class Base{
public:
    Base(){
            std::cout << "Base C-tor is called " << std::endl;
    }
    void fun(){
            std::cout << "Base fun() is called " << std::endl;
    }
    void sorrow(){
            std::cout << "Base Sorrow is called " << std::endl;
    }
    ~Base(){
            std::cout << "Base D-tor is called " << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(){

Base *b1;
b1->fun();
b1->sorrow();
}
```

Below is the output of this piece of code:

```
Base fun() is called 
Base Sorrow is called
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior, not _working code_.

Comment: A function which do never access any data member in the object should be static. It is also questionable if the design you show is useful. Writing C like functions and add class around is not object orientated programming at all. Accessing uninitialized pointers is simply undefined behaviour. That the compiler optimize the unused pointer away did not mean that you wrote valid code at all.

Answer (score 2):

Despite invoking undefined behavior, your code gives an appearance of working because of the way the compiler invokes non-virtual member functions. In case of your `fun()` and `sorrow()` member functions, no access to the instance is performed, so the function completes as if it worked (even though its invocation remains invalid).

If you declare your functions `virtual`, the likelihood of a crash would go up considerably (although you can't guarantee anything with undefined behavior):

```
virtual void fun(){
        std::cout << "Base fun() is called " << std::endl;
}
virtual void sorrow(){
        std::cout << "Base Sorrow is called " << std::endl;
}
```

Calling virtual functions require accessing the instance of the class for the location of the function. Since the pointer is uninitialized, the code is very likely to crash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes with virtual , it crashed. Regarding the access to object, I tried to assign value of some variable in fun() which is a private member of this class. It printed correct value what I had assigned to it.

Comment: @RahulSaraswat Although all UBs are equally invalid, their probability of causing a crash is different. Generally, anything that has to do with executing CPU instructions, such as function calls, has higher probability of causing a crash than reading or writing a junk memory location (which is what happens when you access a private variable using an uninitialized pointer).